# xelatex hangs when using fontspec

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec

I'm using TexStudio 2.5.1 on Windows 7 with MiKTeX. The following brief .tex file will cause xelatex to hang:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Using this command to compile:

```
xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex
```

By 'hang', I mean that the xelatex process will take up an entire core and 200+ MB of memory, and not finish after several minutes. I get no error messages because the process never finishes.

If I comment out the fontspec line, it doesn't hang. But I'd like to use the fontspec package in my document. Why does it hang and how can I fix it?

---

As a side note, using lualatex instead of xelatex will succeed, but then using `\setmainfont{Georgia}` will make that hang as well.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You mention the operating system (Windows 7) and front end (TeX Studio) you use; which TeX distribution do you use? This may be important -- e.g., I use MacTeX2012 running under MacOSX 10.8.2, and your MWE (with or without the `\usepackage{fontspec}` directive) compiles just fine under XeLaTeX on this system. Incidentally, since you use TeXStudio, why are you issuing compile directives from a command line? And, have you tried executing "xelatex test" from the command line?

Comment: @JeffE Have you configured your default compiler to be `XeLaTeX`?

Comment: @hpesoj626 - I apologize for not making one of my questions clear enough: I wasn't asking *how* to configure TeXstudio, *but* why the OP doesn't seem to be using TeXstudio's front-end capabilities to compile the .tex file.

Comment: @Mico: Sorry, I forgot to mention -- I'm using MiKTeX (latest version). I did actually use the built-in compile tool, I only pasted the command line in case it was relevant. `xelatex test` eventually gives me `! Undefined control sequence.`

Comment: @hpesoj626: Yes, I've selected XeLaTeX as the default compiler in TexStudio's build options.

Comment: I just did a fresh install of both MiKTeX and TexStudio on another machine, and the problem persists.

Comment: I also have MiKTeX on a Win7 machine. Your test document runs to the end here (I used TeXnicCenter) – with the normal break for updating the font cache, what takes some time and needs about 200 MB. If you get an error for `xelatex` on the command line, then there’s something wrong with your MiKTeX installation.

Comment: @Speravir: Thanks, it didn't occur to me that it was updating the font cache. I just needed to let it run its full course. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Usually the first run takes time. next `xetex` run will be faster. `xetex opentype-info` on the [Texlive command line test cases](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-390003.5) for xetex. `pdflatex sample2e` for `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fontspec` uses a font caching system. This cache needs to be created first and later updated on a regular basis. Upon creation or updating some information about all TrueType and OpenType fonts installed in your TeX distribution *and in your operating system* is collected.
<sup><sub>(About the algorithms behind collecting and updating, how often or some kind of trigger or so, an expert has to answer.)</sub></sup>

Depending on, how many fonts you have installed, these operations take some time, especially on the very first run, of course. That’s the reason, why you observed the hanging in both `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

Comment: Thanks for the info: it started compiling a single page document ten minutes ago and it's still running O_o I must have too many fonts installed :-/

Comment: Ah, the old "verbosity is for less hardcore programs".